# MissingTemplate for AJAX click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have looked through a lot of these questions and don't seem to be able to piece together this issue about a missing template. I know normally it shows up if there is a partial missing or it doesn't know what to render/redirect_to next, however I thought I had it all setup.

These views are all inside the Comments folder:

show.html.erb

```
</p><%= link_to 'Show partial', comment_show_got_this_path(current_comment.id), remote: true %></p>
<div id="interactionContainer"></div>
```

_show_got_this.html.erb

```
<h1 class="text-center"><%= current_user.name %> has this!</h1>
```

_show_got_this.js.erb

```
$('#interactionContainer').html('<%=j render partial: 'comments/show_got_this' %>')
```

Then in my Comments Controller:

```
def show_got_this
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js   # show_rec_horses.js.erb
  end
end
```

And in my routes:

```
resources :comments do
  get 'show_got_this'
end
```

I'm not getting an error on the app, but in the console I am getting this when I click my link:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms
[Rollbar] Reporting exception: Missing template comments/show_got_this, application/show_got_this with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/vagrant/.../app/views"
  * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
  * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views"
  * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/app/views"

[Rollbar] Exception not reported because Rollbar is disabled

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template comments/show_got_this, application/show_got_this with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/vagrant/.../app/views"
  * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
  * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views"
  * "/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:76:in `show_got_this'
```

Any help or tips are appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Since `show_got_this` is a proper controller action, it should get its own fully-fledged template, right? You are merely providing a partial. Try and see if removing the leading underscore in the view files `_show_got_this.*` helps.

Comment: Thank you, that was it except I needed to keep the html.erb view a partial since that is what is being rendered in the js.erb.

I appreciate this and never even thought that a route renders a template and not just a partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the *js_erb file to a full view instead of a partial solved the problem for me.